# SFINAE failure serializing shared pointer

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, sfinae

I am trying to specialize the boost serialize template for a shared pointer to objects with a specific base class using boost 1.58, gcc 5.4 in c++14 mode.   I believe I have the right SFINAE setup to specialize the function, but the compiler won't select the function as I expect it to.

```
#include <memory>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>

class Artifact {
public:
  Artifact() {}
  virtual ~Artifact() {} // make polymorphic
};

class TestArtifact: public Artifact {
public:
  TestArtifact() : Artifact() {}
};


namespace boost {
namespace serialization {
template <class Archive, class T>
void serialize(Archive &ar,
               std::shared_ptr<typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Artifact,T>::value,T>::type>& artifact,
               //std::shared_ptr<T>& artifact,
               unsigned int version) {
  // save common Artifact structure on save ...

  // Use factory to create specific Artifact (like TestArtifact) shared pointer
  // from common Artifact info on load
}

}
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  auto t = std::make_shared<TestArtifact>();

  std::cout << typeid(std::shared_ptr<TestArtifact>).name() << std::endl;
  std::cout << typeid(std::shared_ptr<typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Artifact,TestArtifact>::value,TestArtifact>::type>).name() << std::endl;

  std::ofstream ofs(argv[1]);
  boost::archive::binary_oarchive ar(ofs);
  ar << t;
}
```

When I build this code (with g++ -std=c++14 -o test_template test_template.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_serialization), I get the following error (after the normal nigh infinite list of "required froms"),

```
/usr/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:118:9: error: ‘class std::shared_ptr<TestArtifact>’ has no member named ‘serialize’
         t.serialize(ar, file_version);
```

Which tells me I am not getting the SFINAE setup correct.  When I swap the commented out line to specialize on `std::shared_ptr<T>`, the code builds and runs as expected, but I do not want to stomp on the standard boost shared pointer serialize specialization.   When I run with the overly general specialization and print the type ID of `std::shared_ptr<TestArtifact>` and the SFINAE class output, they are the same (with this compiler, I get an output of 
`St10shared_ptrI12TestArtifactE` for both), so I don't understand why my SFINAE'd serialize function is not getting recognized.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `T` can't be deduced here.

Instead of putting the `std::enable_if` in the function parameter, put it in a separate template parameter.

```
template <class Archive, class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Artifact,T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void serialize(Archive &ar, std::shared_ptr<T>& artifact, unsigned int version) { ... }
```

Comment: I tried that, and it works stand-alone, but as soon as I include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.h>, which has a serialize defined for shared_ptr<T>, I get a raft of errors complaining about ambiguously overloading serialize with the plain <Archive, shared_ptr<T>> from boost and the specialized <Archive, shared_ptr<T>, extra SFINAE type>.  So that won't work either, as I am trying to get my specialized serialize to play well with boost's shared_ptr serialize.

Comment: ```/usr/include/boost/serialization/serialization.hpp:128:18: error: call of overloaded ‘serialize(boost::archive::binary_oarchive&, std::shared_ptr<TestArtifact>&, const boost::serialization::version_type&)’ is ambiguous```
``` [with Archive = boost::archive::binary_oarchive; T = std::shared_ptr<TestArtifact>]```
```[with Archive = boost::archive::binary_oarchive; T = TestArtifact; typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Artifact, T>::value>::type* <anonymous> = 0u]```

Comment: @JayGowdy Your options to make that work is fairly limited AFAIK. You can modify the boost serialize function, to disable it whenever something derived from Artifact is used. You could alternatively make your own serialize only accept `std::shared_ptr<Artifact>`, that would make it "less templated" and thus a better match.